# Input string was not in a correct format. ASP.NET VB

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, vb.net

I am getting error on page which is run correctly on local host but when put on server display error.

Error is Displaying like.

> [FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
>          Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ParseDouble(String
>   Value, NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat) +181
>          Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToDouble(String
>   Value, NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat) +63
>
> [InvalidCastException: Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.]
>          Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToDouble(String
>   Value, NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat) +207
>          Infinity_Billing.BillNS.taxation(String Gross) +485
>          Infinity_Billing.BillNS.Period_TextChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) +708
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox.OnTextChanged(EventArgs e) +116
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox.RaisePostDataChangedEvent() +50
>          System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox.System.Web.UI.IPostBackDataHandler.RaisePostDataChangedEvent()
>   +10
>          System.Web.UI.Page.RaiseChangedEvents() +132
>          System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +1644

I assume the error is in function from taxation and Period_TextChanged.

Update the error page on local host on multiple times and working fine on localhost for the same page perfectly.

The Code for the Taxation and Period Textchanged on row gridview is like below.

```
Protected Sub Period_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim ddl As TextBox = TryCast(sender, TextBox)
        For Each row As GridViewRow In Gridview1.Rows
            Dim quan As Control = TryCast(row.FindControl("Qty"), TextBox)
            Dim post As Control = TryCast(row.FindControl("Post"), DropDownList)
            Dim prd As Control = TryCast(row.FindControl("Period"), TextBox)
            If prd IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim ddl1 As DropDownList = DirectCast(post, DropDownList)
                Dim ddl2 As TextBox = DirectCast(quan, TextBox)
                Dim ddl3 As TextBox = DirectCast(prd, TextBox)
                If ddl.ClientID = ddl3.ClientID Then
                    Dim amt As TextBox = TryCast(row.FindControl("Amount"), TextBox)
                    Dim txt As TextBox = TryCast(row.FindControl("Rate"), TextBox)
                    If ddl3 Is Nothing Then
                        MsgBox("Please Insert Nos. of Days Present", vbOKOnly, "Days")
                        ddl3.Focus()
                    ElseIf Monthlist.SelectedValue = 0 Then
                        MsgBox("Please Select Month", vbOKOnly, "Month")
                        Monthlist.Focus()
                    Else
                        amt.Text = ddl1.SelectedValue * ddl2.Text * ddl3.Text / DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Now.Year, Monthlist.SelectedValue)
                        GrandTotal()
                        taxation(Gross_Amount.Text)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next


Private Sub taxation(Gross As String)
        If aggrmnt.SelectedValue = 0 Then
            MsgBox("Select Aggrement Before Billing", vbOKOnly, "Info")
        Else
            Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(strConnString)
                Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    cmd.CommandText = "Command Text Here"
                    Dim dt As New DataTable()
                    con.Open()
                    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    dt.Load(reader)
                    ESIC_Amt.Text = ((Gross * dt.Rows(0).Item("ESICDed").ToString.Trim()) / 100)
                    EPF_Amt.Text = ((Gross * dt.Rows(0).Item("EPFDed").ToString.Trim()) / 100)
                    Service_Chrg.Text = ((Gross * dt.Rows(0).Item("Ser_Charge").ToString.Trim()) / 100)
                    Dim temp As Integer = dt.Rows(0).Item("ServiceTaxDed").ToString.Trim()
                    Dim tempttl As Integer = (Val(ESIC_Amt.Text) + Val(EPF_Amt.Text) + Val(Service_Chrg.Text) + Val(Gross))
                    Service_Amt.Text = (tempttl * temp / 100)
                    NetAmt.Text = Val(tempttl) + Val(Service_Amt.Text)
                    con.Close()
                End Using
            End Using
        End If
```

[image: When update the days error Occur on the page.]

and the days change fire the period_textchaged event from the code above.

The code for the GRAND TOTAL is like below

```
Private Sub GrandTotal()
        Dim GTotal As Integer
        For i As Integer = 0 To Gridview1.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim total As Integer = DirectCast(Gridview1.Rows(i).FindControl("Amount"), TextBox).Text
            If total.ToString.Length <= 0 Then
                total = 0
            Else
                GTotal += total
            End If
            'For Each total As [String] In TryCast(Gridview1.Rows(i).FindControl("Amount"), Label).Text
        Next
        Gross_Amount.Text = GTotal.ToString()
    End Sub
```

Comment: You tell us that the error message says that the input string was not in the correct format but nowhere do you actually tell us what the input string was. That suggests that you don't know, which means that you haven't looked, which means that you shouldn't even have posted a question here yet. You're supposed to do what you can for yourself first and then, if you do post here, provide us with all the relevant information. The data in use and the line on which the exception was thrown are ALWAYS relevant information.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I update the Question with the screenshot and details

Comment: The error means your code is trying to convert an empty string into a number. Casting to Double fails. You need to debug and validate those strings before performing math operations with them. VB allows you to do things like `Dim result As String = "3" * "4"` which is a bad practice.

Comment: @derloopkat I know that but on which part it done conversation all code is in question

Comment: @AtulSharma, do you know how to debug?

Comment: Actually am starter in developing line. A little bit knowledge.

Comment: @AtulSharma, well, the stack trace also include line numbers where the errors can be found. But if you're a beginner you need to learn how to debug.

Comment: But on local host it's work perfectly

Comment: Find the line, identify the variable and if empty, assign a default value that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the reply . I apply your suggestion and mark it answer if success.

Comment: @derloopkat i tried your solution but did not works for me.

Comment: Seems that your 'Gross' parameter in 'transaction' method is empty in (at least) one of the loops. TryParse it at the beginning of the method to check for a valid value.

Comment: @DIe Updated the question with the required function but still not clear.

Comment: I would check if GTotal is 0, then manually set `Gross_Amount.Text = "0"` just in case the ToString method retrieves an empty string... and apart from that what I already told you, in taxation method's first line, try parse the 'Gross' parameter to avoid empty string